# How to send updates from long running goroutine?

Tags: go

I have a goroutine for a long running job. When the job is done, it pushes the results to a channel. In the meantime, while the job is running, I want to keep updating an API with the status RUNNING.

So far, I have the following code :

```
func getProgressTimeout() <-chan time.Time {
    return time.After(5 * time.Minute)
}

func runCommand(arg *Request) {
    chanResult := make(chan Results)

    go func(args *Request, c chan Results) {
        resp, err := execCommand(args)
        c <- Results{
            resp: resp,
            err:  err,
        }
    }(arg, chanResult)

    var err error

progressLoop:
    for {
        select {
        case <-getProgressTimeout():
            updateProgress()  // this method will send status= RUNNING to a REST API

        case out := <-chanResult:
            err = jobCompleted(request, out)
            break progressLoop
        }
    }
    return err
}
```

I am new to golang. And I have reached the above code after lot of trial and error, and googling. It's working now. Still it doesn't feel intuitive to me when I look at it (this may very well be because, I am still trying to learn the Go way of doing things). So my question is, can I refactor this into better shape? Is there some existing pattern which is applicable in this kind of scenario? Or if there is some totally different approach to keep sending periodic updates while job is running?

Also, any suggestions to improve upon my golang concurrency are also appreciated. :)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider using [time.NewTicker](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#NewTicker), which sends a periodic value to a channel. Here's an example from the documentation:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    ticker := time.NewTicker(time.Second)
    defer ticker.Stop()
    done := make(chan bool)
    go func() {
        time.Sleep(10 * time.Second)
        done <- true
    }()
    for {
        select {
        case <-done:
            fmt.Println("Done!")
            return
        case t := <-ticker.C:
            fmt.Println("Current time: ", t)
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the embedded goroutine invoking `func` emulates a long task by sleeping for 10 seconds, while the caller uses `select` to wait for the result, while also receiving periodic events from the ticker - this is where you can do the API progress update.

Comment: But what advantage will this have over time.After? Apart from that, both solutions kind of look same. I was hoping that there might be a better way of doing whole logic inside for loop. Or some different approach altogether instead of reading values from two channels. Is that possible?

Comment: @user270386: this is the most general solution, and it's easier than rolling your own function with `time.After`. It's general because it allows you actual goroutine to do any blocking thing. Doing blocking operations in goroutines is idiomatic in Go because it results in the simplest code.  Channels and selects are the idiomatic Go approach for mutliplexing concurrent processes.